# How to replace last occurrence of pattern in a third last line of a file

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a file in which i want replace last occurrence of string in third to the last line in a file. I have a file like:

```
  analyze_compression_testpoints -log no -TESTMODE FULLSCAN
  -EXPERIMENT <br /> azul_rrfa -outputfile
  ./testresults/testinsertion.file<br />
</body>
</html>
```

I want to replace `<br />` with `</font>` in the third last line only.
I am using:

```
sed -i "s|\(.*\)<br />\$|\1</font>|g"
```

but it is replacing all the last occurrence in each line, but i want only last occurrence of file, not each line.

Answer (score 8):

With `sed`:

```
tac file | sed '3 s|<br />$|</font>|' | tac
```

With `ed`:

```
echo -e '$-2s/<br \/>$/<\/font>/\nw' | ed -s file
```

With `vim`:

```
:$-2 s!<br />$!</font>!
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but how to insert in a file, as sed -i is not working in this case. I want to insert/replace directly from command.

Comment: @Rash Use the `ed` solution.

Comment: ed is also not working here. giving output as question mark (?). Please suggest.

Comment: @Rash I suggest you try the `ed` solution exactly the way I wrote it.

Comment: Yes, I have tried exactly the same command but not working, I am running it on shell prompt.

Comment: It works fine here with GNU `ed` 1.14.2.

Answer (score 0):

As this is the last occurrence in the file, you can use this `sed` script:

```
sed -i 'H;1h;$!d;g;s_\(.*\)<br />_\1</font>_' yourfile.html
```

or simplified with GNU `sed` and extended regular expression:

```
sed -izE 's_(.*)<br />_\1</font>_' yourfile.html
```

The trick is to process the whole file in one buffer. The POSIX version does this by collecting in the hold buffer, the GNU version uses option `-z` for this. Then, with `s` command replace everything (`.*`) including the last occurrence of the pattern by everything before the pattern (the `\1` refers to the part in `()`) and the replacement.

Other attempt, if you really require to replace only on the third to last line (no replacement if there is no match, no replacing on the next-to-last or last line):

```
sed '1N;N;$!{P;D];s_<br />_</font>_' yourfile.html
```